# Making coherent sheaves with nonvanishing higher Chern classes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, examples, chern-classes

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent sheaf on a variety $X$, and assume $\mathcal{F}$ has generic rank $n$. I expect (see e.g. [here](https://www.uni-due.de/%7Ehm0002/Artikel/CohNote_v1a.pdf)) that this actually puts no conditions on its Chern classes $c_1(\mathcal{F}),c_2(\mathcal{F}),...$ . Constrast this with the vector bundle case, where all Chern classes above the $n$th will vanish. However, I have no idea how to construct examples with this non-vanishing property.

**Question:** Fix $n\ge 0$. For each positive integer $k$, is there a nice example of a variety $X_k$ with a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}_k$ of generic rank $n$ and $c_k(\mathcal{F}_k)\ne 0$?

Even the rank $n=1$ case seems unclear to me. I imagine it might be possible to answer the question using for $X_k$ projective spaces or partial flag varieties, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Why does the title of this question differ from the title on the list of new questions?

Comment: @JasonStarr I edited it to improve the title and I think it takes a minute to update.

Comment: Surely there's a typo in the current title? Should be "making"?

Comment: For $n=1$ and any $k$ you can consider the ideal sheaf of a subvariety of codimension $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any affine variety $X$ of dimension $k$ which has a vector bundle $E$ of rank $k$ with $c_k(E)\neq 0$. If $n\geq k$ take $F=E\oplus O_X^{n-k}$. If $n<k$ take $F$ to be the quotient of $E$ by $k-n$ general sections of $E$.